# Github: Page build timed out

Tags: github, r-markdown

I am using distill to create new posts. I can render my markdown file and produce the html output that I want.
For some time, it was complaining UTF-8 encoding. I added encoding: UTF-8 in my site.yaml file. That error doesn't appear again. However, after pushing my changes to my GitHub repository, I receive another error. I tried it several times. I don't think it is because of the repository disk quota.

*The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error: Page build timed out. Please try again later.* I have no idea what is happening. I am new to GitHub pages. I wish someone can help me solve this.

[My GitHub repository](https://github.com/Mihiretukebede/mihiretukebede.gitlub.io)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got any solution. Here is what I did. The cause of this UTF-8 problem was the non-English characters in my BibTeX files. Bib2df didn't recognize the utf-8 characters. I read the file and then selected my relevant variables and then I write.xslx file and removed all BibTeX files from the repository. By reading my excel file I did my analysis and pushed my changes. All changes have got went live..... awesome.